# Getting HTML value from Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Is there a way to get HTML contents from TinyMCE editor using jQuery so I can copy this over to another div?

I tried several methods like val() on content but it doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are initilizing with jquery adaptor

```
 $(selector).tinyMCE().getContent();
```

Comment: Can you help me over this issue [my-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213204/unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-sending-tinymce-data-using-ajax)  @Charlietfl

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content">
$('#content').html()
```

Using TinyMce API:

```
$('#content').tinymce().activeEditor.getContent() // overall html
$('#content').tinymce().activeEditor.getContent({format : 'text'}) // overall text
$('#content').tinymce().selection.getContent() // selected html
$('#content').tinymce().selection.getContent({format : 'text'})) // selected text
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using tinymce, i would use it's internal methods to get the content you need.  when i need to get content within the active editor, i do this:

```
var rawString = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

i invoke that method within an event handler function.

here is the documentation:

[tinymce api](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

Answer (score 1):

use TinyMCE's API to get it:

```
alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text();` instead of `val();`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying charlietfl method:  `$(selector).tinyMCE().getContent();`

There was an error:

```
[$(selector).tinyMCE().getContent();][1]
```

This way with `activeEditor` worked for me:

[activeEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mahKY.jpg)

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()
```

[Source](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/)

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".btnClassClose", function () {

        var tinyMCEcontent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

        var getAttrIDArray = [];


        $("#" + getelementId).html("");
        $("#" + getelementId).html(tinyMCEcontent);
        $("#" + getelementId).append(buttonEDI);

 
        var PageName = new Object();
        PageName["mdlPageId"] = getelementId;
        getAttrIDArray.push(PageName);

        var PageName = new Object();
        PageName["mdlPageContentHtml"] = tinyMCEcontent;
        getAttrIDArray.push(PageName);


        var PageName = new Object();
        PageName["mdlPageName"] = "Default";
        getAttrIDArray.push(PageName);

        var PageName = new Object();
        PageName["mdlAligen"] = "Central";
        getAttrIDArray.push(PageName);

        var PageName = new Object();
        PageName["mdlOrderNumberHorizontal"] = "1";
        getAttrIDArray.push(PageName);


        alert(JSON.stringify(getAttrIDArray));


        var contentGetAttrIDArray = SecondMainSendAjax("CMS?handler=Content", getAttrIDArray);
      
    });
});
```