# Unexpected end of JSON input while sending tinyMCE data using Ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, tinymce

I am using `tinyMCE` for some user data and to save that data i am using `Ajax` to send data.

When I tried to save the data using ajax i get this two errors:

> parsererror
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (after Some changes i get this another error)

Here is my code.This is the `HTML` code:

```
<textarea id="cover_letter" name="cover_letter" class="cover_letter_tinyMCE"></textarea> 
<button type="button" class="btn" id="save_cover_letter">Save Cove Letter</button>
```

This is the Ajax:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save_cover_letter", function (e) {     
e.preventDefault();
     
var cover_letter_text = tinyMCE.editors[$('.cover_letter_tinyMCE').attr('id')].getContent(); 
console.log(cover_letter_text);

    $.ajax({                    
        url: save_url,
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',           
        data: {'cover_letter':cover_letter_text},    
        dataType: 'json',                               
        success : function(response) {      
          alert(response);
          console.log(response);                  
        },               
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);    
        }
        
    });
      
 });
```

Comment: Problem is in server side response not returning valid json. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see exactly what response data looks like. Guessing there is html in there based on the `<` being first character

Comment: I am sending user data from `TinyMCE` so the data is like `<p>Test Data</p>` this type of data i get from `TinyMCE` @charlietfl

Comment: But you are requesting `dataType:'json'` and that is html

Comment: I have try the  dataType:'HTML' but still same error @charlietfl

Comment: Can't be same error...that is a json parsing error

Comment: ok sir let me check again sorry for the incontinent behavior @charlietfl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149711/discussion-between-always-a-learner-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Now the `json` error is gone but could look like it did not go to my URL. in my log it shows that all page data is loded back again

Comment: I get my HTML page in console log. @charlietfl

Comment: Not sure what you expect returned from `save_url`. Again inspect in browser dev tools network to see if request is going where you expect it to

Comment: I have used ajax before many times but with `TinyMCE` it is first time i think i have to drop the idea of using ajax. I get my whole html page in ajax response in which i have tried to check with simple echo but not get what the problem is. Thanks u all for the suggestions.

Comment: No reason can't use ajax. Just not clear what you are trying to accomplish with the response or what you are actually returning. Your problem is with the php, not the javascript

Comment: Used Form searlize and it gives the error are `SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0` @charlietfl

Comment: still a back end problem

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the very useful suggestions but now finally i have find the error my codeigntier validation   is creating a problem and that's a different issue. thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

Use Form HTML

```
<form id="cover_letter">
    <textarea  name="cover_letter" class="cover_letter_tinyMCE"></textarea> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="save_cover_letter">Save Cove Letter</button>
</form>
```

AND jQuery

```
$(document).on("submit", "#cover_letter", function (e)
{     
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.ajax({                    
        url: save_url,
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',           
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',                               
        success : function(response) {      
          alert(response);
          console.log(response);                  
        },               
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);    
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Tried your Solution but still got the same error. @MikeSouto

Comment: Hi, sorry... in my example change "#save_cover_letter" by "#cover_letter". And check that load jquery before de script code

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I recommend trying following:

1) See whether your "save_url" script returns any unclosed < through echo.

2) Also check whether your console.log(cover_letter_text) outputs the desired content from the text area.